# Proper way to update dictionary embedded in another dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's assume a dictionary exists like:

```
a = {'b': {}}
```

Say I have a set of statements like this that take action on the dictionary:

```
c = a['b']
c['a'] =  1
```

a will now read as `{'b': {'a': 1}}`

In coding an application, would this be a proper way to update an embedded dictionary or are their some side effects to working like this?

Comment: Why don't you simply write `a = {'b': {'a': 1}}`

Comment: The only thing is it's not very readable in my opinion, but that's all it is, an opinion. @WillemVanOnsem example above me is probably better

Comment: If `a` already exists, and looks like this: `{'b': {}}`, then it's more readable (IMHO) to update it with `a['b']['a'] = 1`. And if the 'b' sub-dict doesn't exist yet, do `a['b'] = {'a': 1}`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's obviously a theoretical question.  Say the dictionary already exists but the embedded dictionary needs to be added, or a key needs to be added to it.  Then you couldn't just add it on creation.

Comment: @Rob: in that case you can write `a['b'] = {'a':1}`

Comment: I'm asking due to a code review, I wanted to check if there was something wrong with the way someone was doing this.  Seemed off to me but wanted to get the opinion of SO

Comment: @Rob: I did not dv'ed this question (so no problem). The way this is written is not wrong, but it is extremely verbose. Now of course the amount of lines is not always the best indicator about readability. But this code is not "self explaining" like they say. So personally I would rewrite that somehow if I found this somewhere in a repository.

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly fine, and preferable if the dimensions have long names or are in different domains. It also helps with debugging since it makes it easier to see what is in a problem variable if you have a large datastructure.

There's nothing wrong with `a['b']['a'] = 1` either. Use whichever makes the code easier to read.